# Equivalent to Unix eval in Windows

Tags: windows, shell, scripting

Was wondering how you'd do the following in Windows:

From a c shell script (extension csh), I'm running a Python script within an 'eval' method so that the output from the script affects the shell environment. Looks like this:

```
eval `python -c "import sys; run_my_code_here(); "`
```

Was wondering how I would do something like the eval statement in Windows using Windows' built in CMD shell. I want to run a Python script within a Windows script and have the script run what the Python script prints out.

** update: specified interest in running from CMD shell.

Comment: Please be specific about which shell you are using.  CMD is my best guess, but maybe you mean PowerShell or a Windows port of CSH.

Answer (score 13):

If it's in `cmd.exe`, using a temporary file is the only option [that I know of]:

```
python -c "print(\"Hi\")" > temp.cmd
call temp.cmd
del temp.cmd
```

Answer (score 3):

(Making some guesses where details are missing from your question)

In CMD, when a batch script modifies the environment, the default behavior is that it modifies the environment of the CMD process that is executing it.

Now, if you have a batch script that calls another batch script, there are 3 ways to do it.

1. execute the batch file directly:

   ```
   REM call q.bat
   q.bat
   REM this line never runs
   ```

   Usually you don't want this, because it won't return to the calling batch script.  This is more like `goto` than `gosub`.  The CMD process just switches from one script to another.
2. execute with `call`:

   ```
   REM call q.bat
   CALL q.bat
   REM changes that q.bat affects will appear here.
   ```

   This is the most common way for one batch file to call another.  When `q.bat` exits, control will return to the caller.  Since this is the same CMD process, changes to the environment will still be there.

   Note: If `q.bat` uses the `EXIT` statement, it can cause the CMD process to terminate, without returning control to the calling script.

   Note 2: If `q.bat` uses `EXIT /B`, then the CMD process will not exit.  This is useful for setting `ERRORLEVEL`.
3. Execute in a new CMD process:

   ```
   REM call q.bat
   CMD /C q.bat
   REM environment changes in q.bat don't affect me
   ```

   Since q.bat run ins a new CMD process, it affects the environment of that process, and not the CMD that the caller is running in.

   Note: If `q.bat` uses `EXIT`, it won't terminate the process of the caller.

---

The `SETLOCAL` CMD command will create a new environment for the current script.  Changes in that environment won't affect the caller.  In general, `SETLOCAL` is a good practice, to avoid leaking environment changes by accident.

To use `SETLOCAL` and still push environment changes to the calling script, end the script with:

```
    ENDLOCAL && SET X=%X% && SET Y=%Y%
```

This will push the values of X and Y to the parent environment.

---

If on the other hand you want to run another process (not a CMD script) and have it affect the current script's environment, than have the tool generate a batch file that makes the changes you want, then execute that batch file.

```
    REM q.exe will write %TEMP%\runme.cmd, which looks like:
    REM     set X=Y
    q.exe
    call "%TEMP%\runme.cmd"
```