# putenv() can not set environment variable for parent command line

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd, command-line-interface

I need to set some environment variable by php and access them from windows cmd. From cmd I call php with `call php\php.exe install.php 0` then `install.php` will set some environment variable. when execution of `install.php` is finished then I tried to get those variables from parent cmd. But cmd can not get those values.

here is my `install.php`:

```
<?php
$config = json_decode(file_get_contents('tmp/config.json'), true);
foreach ($config[$argv[1]] as $segment=>$details){
    putenv("targetFolder=$segment");
    putenv("targetLink=$details[link]");
}
echo getenv('targetFolder');
```

here is result:

[image: cmd output]

`%targetFolder%` should return `servers`

Comment: `Call` is used for other batch files or labels within the same script, it is not used for third party executables. Please remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With setenv, you able to set variables for the current process, and `cmd.exe` is the different, parent one. You [cannot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38205) change the env of parent process without hacks. You probably should rewrite the script to put necessary `set ENV=VALUE` lines into some temporary batch file and then [call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195651/8547799) it.

```
<?php
$config = json_decode(file_get_contents('tmp/config.json'), true);
$tmpBatch = fopen('tmp/setenv.bat', 'w');
foreach ($config[$argv[1]] as $segment=>$details){
    fwrite($tmpBatch, "set targetFolder=$segment");
    fwrite($tmpBatch, "set targetLink=$details[link]");
}
fclose($tmpBatch);
```

And then

```
php\php.exe install.php
call tmp\setenv.bat
```